# Prove that a function is differentiable and its derivative function is integrable

Tags: differential

> Suppose $f:D \subset  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and satisfies the Lipschitz condition,that is
> $$\exists M>0, \forall x,y\in D:|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|.$$
> I want to know whether $f'(x)$  exists  for  all $x\in D$ and  whether it is
> Riemannian integrable on $D$.

By Lebesgue's Theorem I know that $f'(x)$ exists almost everywhere on $D$ and that $f'(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $D$. That's because $f(x)$ is an absolutely continuous function. But I don't know what to do next. Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

$D=[0,1], f(x)=|x|$ shows that $f'(x)$ need not exist for all $x$. For $f'$ to be Riemann integrable, it has to be defined at all points (and it has to be bounded).

Comment: Thank you.This example helps me.I also want to know whether the function (f'(x))that I say is Riemmanian integrable or not? I think f'(x) is Lebesgue integrable.